# Skewed div with normal text inside in scss

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make something like this

[image]

My best bet so far is

```css
header {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100px;
  transform: skewX(15deg) skewY(10deg);
  background: #284C5C;
  position: relative;
  //left: 80px;
  //top: -80px;
  height: 400px;
}
  
h1 {
  transform: skewX(-15deg) skewY(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
</header>
```

but that doesn't get me all the way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add up a stack snippet with all the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider transform-origin and use pseudo element to avoid the invert skewing on the text:

```css
h1 {
  padding-bottom:200px;
  position: relative;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
  margin:0;
}
h1:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background: #284C5C;  
  transform: skewX(10deg) skewY(6deg) ;
  transform-origin:top right;
  border-radius:0 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

Comment: Very neat. Is it possible to calculate where the bend happens in the lower left? I want to set the margin based on that.

Comment: @mr.bjerre in this case, remove the text-align and apply padding (ex : `padding-left: 20px;`). You only need a fixed value since the angle is the same so the distance will remain the same

Comment: But it wouldn’t account for different widths / responsiveness. Right?

Comment: Also; do you have a suggestion on how to create the grey box under the green? (I have the box made but it is under the white background - using css grid on those elements)